# WordPress - Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error #200

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, wordpress, learndash

I am working on the Leandash project , In which I have displayed the **Leandash "Quiz setting Tab"** from back-end ( https://prnt.sc/12uoikj ) to Front-end ( https://prnt.sc/12uok4v )

Now ALL the fields are working fine , except **toggle fields**

For example : When we turn ON toggle , it will show sub-fieds like this : https://prnt.sc/12uomvr

But it is NOT working in front-end , Showing Minified React error : https://prnt.sc/12uos4s

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Hi Parthavi, there does seem to be link that the minified error asks to go to. What does that say? Also, major question, I am not aware of learndash much, but isn't the learndash quizzing system meant be used from the backend side? If yes, then you might just not be calling all the required js files

Comment: @shivaramanaiyer 
Yes ,  it is used from the back-end only , but my requirement is to Bring All Settings on Frontend

Comment: I thought so. Check the link in the Minified React error on the console to see what might be causing it. 

As I said earlier, may be you are missing something js file/component in the Front-end

Comment: Minify JS causing error here : https://prnt.sc/12uq5gs 
which I am not getting

Comment: Based on the link show in the error: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=200 it seems to be that the target doesn't exist or something. You might have to go down the trace to find out what caused. 

But then again, you are doing something the plugin developers didn't intend as default behaviour so difficult to say exactly what you might be missing.